# ebay api FiexedPriceTransaction notification and get the updated item quantity

Tags: xml, notifications, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

When the FixedPriceTransaction is sent, I need to know what is the new quantity of the item purchased, so if I call GetItem api, have the info of the item purchased quantity decreased ( updated quantity )?